# Issues with sending JSON Payload using Curl through command line / Shell. The same works well when using a Json file

Tags: json, curl

I have run into an issue where I am trying to send a JSON payload to a server through curl using the terminal

curl -v -u admin:admin123 --header "Content-Type: application/json" 'http://localhost:8080/service/siesta/rest/v1/script/' -d '{"name": "trg_dao","type": "groovy","content": "blobStore.createFileBlobStore('trg_dao','/tmp/trg_dao')"}' and it gets uploaded as

{
  "name" : "trg_dao",
  "content" : "blobStore.createFileBlobStore(trg_dao,/tmp/trg_dao)",
  "type" : "groovy"
}

Where as the same payload uploads correctly as below while using -d @filename (curl -v -g -u admin:admin123 --header "Content-Type: application/json" 'http://localhost:8080/service/siesta/rest/v1/script/' --data-binary @test.json)

{
  "name" : "trg_dao",
  "content" : "blobStore.createFileBlobStore('trg_dao','/tmp/trg_dao')",
  "type" : "groovy"
}

The payload that I am using is

{"name": "trg_dao","type": "groovy","content": "blobStore.createFileBlobStore('trg_dao','/tmp/trg_dao')"}

Any pointers as to where am I going wrong will be very helpful.

Best Regards
Shiva

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue as below

curl -v -u admin:admin123 -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"name": "trg_dao","type": "groovy","content": "blobStore.creaileBlobStore('"'trg_dao'"','"'/tmp/trg_dao'"')"}' 'http://localhost:8080/v1/script/'